# Rotating a conic

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus

The point corresponding to rotating $\phi$ radians (counter-clockwise) a certain point $(x,y)$ is given by $\sigma_{\phi}(x,y)=(x\cos(\phi)-y\sin(\phi), x\sin(\phi)+y\cos(\phi))$. I would want to derive, **only using this**, the equation of a rotated conic. Let's say I have the parabola $y=x^2$ and I want to rotate it $\pi/4$ counter-clockwise. My thoughts: the points of the parabola are of the form $(x,x^2)$, and I can apply $\sigma_{\phi}$ to them. This yields $(x\cos(\phi)-x^2\sin(\phi), x\sin(\phi)+x^2\cos(\phi)$, I don't know how to get the desired formula. Also, I have used that in this particular case, $y$ is a function of $x$, but obviously this is not the general case (if my original parabola had $y=x$ as its axis).

I'm sure the answer is very simple, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x',y')$ be the image of $(x,y$ after rotation anticlockwise by angle $\phi$.

Then $(x,y)$ is the image of $(x',y')$ after rotation by angle $-\phi$

In which case, $$(x,y)=\left(x'\cos(-\phi)-y'\sin(-\phi),x'\sin(-\phi)+y'\cos(-\phi)\right)$$
$$=\left(x'\cos(\phi)+y'\sin(\phi),-x'\sin(\phi)+y'\cos(\phi)\right)$$

Therefore the image of the curve $y=x^2$ is $$-x'\sin(\phi)+y'\cos(\phi)=\left(x'\cos(\phi)+y'\sin(\phi)\right)^2$$

Now you can replace $x'$ with $x$ and $y'$ with $y$, and in the case where $\phi=\frac{\pi}{4}$, you get
$$-x+y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x+y)^2$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was very clear, and it is easy to see that I could do the same for any curve.

Comment: you are welcome